# Is there a way to increment/Update an sqlite table field by one using windows powershell?

Tags: powershell, sqlite

I am using sqlite on a win10 PC. I am setting everything up using .cmd.
I have been trying to increment the values in a table.
The table is :

```
CREATE TABLE History (
[Symbol] varchar(16) NOT NULL,
[Level] float NULL,
[Counter] int NULL
);
```

An example of some of the data in the table is:

| Symbol | Level | Counter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "A" | 254 | 0 |
| "A" | 325 | 0 |
| "A" | 100 | 0 |
| "A" | 110 | 0 |
| "B" | 264 | 0 |
| "B" | 222 | 0 |
| "B" | 120 | 0 |
| "B" | 151 | 0 |
| "B" | 999 | 0 |

I would like to be able to Update the "Counter" ‪field so that it increments by 1 for "A" and then do the same for "B".

| Symbol | Level | Counter |
| --- | --- | --- |
| "A" | 254 | 1 |
| "A" | 325 | 2 |
| "A" | 100 | 3 |
| "A" | 110 | 4 |
| "B" | 264 | 1 |
| "B" | 222 | 2 |
| "B" | 120 | 3 |
| "B" | 151 | 4 |
| "B" | 999 | 5 |

I have tried UPDATE but so far the incremented value doesn't Stick through each iteration of the query.

```
UPDATE History SET Counter = Counter+2 WHERE Symbol = "A" or Symbol = "B";`
```

I would be happy for a solution for "A", so that I can work on getting it to work for "B" as well.

Comment: please search a little more before posting. This tutorial may help:
https://www.google.com/amp/s/michlstechblog.info/blog/powershell-working-with-a-sqlite-database/

Comment: I was hoping to find  solution that stays as close as possible to the native Powershell as possible. It looks like this solution requires installing and maintaining additional software. I would like to avoid the need for supporting/learning new software.